# Why TI stopped supporting CC2530ZDK-ZNP-MINI Kits

Tags: zigbee

I am planning to buy CC2530ZDK-ZNP-MINI Kit for my project on sensor networks as it has most of the sensors that I need but I found out from the TI website that they are not supporting these kits anymore. Does anybody know why TI stopped supporting them??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Now they have the CC2530 booster pack for the MSP430 or Stellaris Launchpad. So you will want to use these, because CC2530ZNP mini kit is discouraged for new developments.

http://www.anaren.com/air/cc2530-boosterpack-kit